# Why are three slides added instead of one when I add a slide to Swiper slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mey9zgfr/7/

For some mysterious reason, when I add one slide in a slider, three slides are added. I've never encountered such a strange problem using Swiper.
Intitally I thought that this bug happens because of slidesPerView param is set to 4, but I only have 1 slide in my Swiper. So I tried to increase amount of slides up to 4, but that didn't work, it gave 12 slides in result.

```js
    let swiper = new Swiper("#albums_slider", {
        direction: "horizontal",
        spaceBetween: 30,
        slidesPerView: 4,
        loop: true,
        allowTouchMove: false,
        speed: 600,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 3000
        },
    
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
        }
    });
```

```css
    #albums_slider {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 150px;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
                flex-direction: column;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        color: var(--third-color)!important;
        text-decoration: none!important;
    }
    .swiper-slide:hover {
        text-decoration: none!important;
    }
    .swiper-slide .title {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .swiper-slide .description {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .swiper-slide .price {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .swiper-slide img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
        outline: none;
        color: #000!important;
    }
```

```html
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div class="swiper-container" id="albums_slider">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <a href="" class="image"><img src="https://paspahang.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/collect-the-incredible-funny-cat-memes-hit-man-of-funny-cat-memes-hit-man.gif" alt=""></a>
            <div class="title">Album1</div>
            <div class="description">Info</div>
            <div class="price">$$$</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

P.S. SO doesn't allow me to post the question due to that "it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details", since I don't have anything else to add, I'd place this here:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
> reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
> pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
> culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: You're loading the Swiper library twice: `swiper-bundle.js` and `swiper-bundle.min.js`. You don't need both of them.

Comment: But removing the duplicates doesn't fix the problem.....

Comment: It looks like it's because of `slidesPerView: 4`, but there aren't enough different slides, so it duplicates them.

Comment: @Barmar I thought the same initially, but then tried to increase amount of slides up to 4, and it gives 12

Answer (score 0):

it think you should use `loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,centeredSlides: true,` in your swiper options

```
loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
centeredSlides: true,
```

@Coder4Fon